# Unable to install OS on a Dell Poweredge 2850

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

As the title states.

Im having an issue trying to install any version of Windows Server.

So far, I have tried 2008 and 2012 R2.

When the server arrived, it contained 3 73GB SCSI drives that had been wiped.

I went into the hardware raid and configured RAID 5. I guess that went ok because everything is green (never configured RAID before).

When I reboot, everythings good, says 1 LOGICAL VOLUME.

It boots either from DVD or USB, but no matter what, after a few minutes of loading files, I get a quick flash on the screen that says YOUR PC MUST REBOOT and then system reboots. I cant get any further than this.

Any suggestions or anything Im missing?

Do I need to install some sort of RAID driver before the Windows Server install will start? Or could the HDD's possibly be bad?

Comment: Please be more descriptive of the installation process.  When you say "after a few minutes", do you mean after you boot the system? after you get into the installation wizard? after you are prompted to select the drive to install to? after you format the drives? after you are prompted that the installation starts and it's copying files?

Comment: The system boots. I get lines and lines of things starting such as the Intel Boot manager and Backplane Manager.

It starts the installation process of the server OS, the loading files phase. But it reboots right before it would actually start the setup screen, such as where you choose language and such.

I never get to the actual install wizard.

Comment: So, you get POST, and you get the controller POST, but you don't get the Windows installation wizard screen?  Can you confirm the system is configured to boot from the media you're using to install the OS?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both USB and DVD and both fail at the same spot.

Comment: Where? After the controller POST? Do you ever get asked to "press any key to boot from CD"?

Comment: It actually never asks to me to press anything. After the controllers POST it goes to Set Up Loading Files. 

After the loading bar gets to 100% it then fails and gives me the error about the PC must reboot, the the server just restarts.

Comment: Is it a Windows "set up" screen? Or does it look like something else is setting up?

Comment: Its the Windows Server 2008R2/2012 loading files screen

[Loading Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36975_01/html/E38045/figures/windows2012-loadingFiles_screen.jpg)

Once it gets to the end, which takes a couple minutes, it then sits there for a few seconds, then gives the error then reboots.

Comment: Does it ask you to "Press 'F6' to install additional drivers"? Or does it crash before it asks you this?

Comment: It just crashes/reboots after it loads. Doesnt ask for me to press anything.

Comment: Can you try pressing 'F6' when the setup screen starts anyway to see if it prompts you for the additional drivers?  If not, then you have a problem with your installation media.

Comment: What happens if you have no CD/DVD or USB stick in? Does it still reboot itself?

Comment: I think its a network boot and it fails.

After everythings POST and where it would start loading files if I had a DVD or USB stick in with a bootable OS install,it says check media cable.

F1 to retry or F2 to enter setup.

Comment: @DominickIntorre I assume you're using known good OS media?

Comment: Yes. I actually tested the media (USB and DVD) on another machine and they booted fine into the installation wizard on the other machine.

I looked into the issue at the Dell support site. What I found is that I may need to look into how the RAID is set up. I also have the RAID controller driver. They suggested using Nlite to slipstream the driver and create a custom disk. I may wipe the RAID settings and remove all but 1 drive, set to RAID 0 and try the Nlite method and see what happens.

Comment: You didn't do your research. The PowerEdge 2850 is a silly beast for OS installs. The easiest route is to use Dell's System Build and Update Utility. Boot to it, that'll help you set up your system so that you can install Windows on it. This one here is compatible with a 2850, Windows 2008 R2 (I don't know if they have one that supports 2012(R2) for a 2850, but I'm guessing no, though maybe you could *shudder* in place upgrade the 2008 R2 to 2012 R2, or use the drivers for 2008 R2 to install 2012 R2): http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=YFF1M

Comment: @austinian your comment should be posted as an answer - this is completely correct, the SBUU is needed for that generation of system to get an OS reinstall going properly. And no, server 2012 is most certainly not supported.

Comment: Bah, alright, I'm just picky about answering low-quality questions.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerEdge 2850 is a silly beast for OS installs.

The easiest route is to use Dell's System Build and Update Utility.

Boot to it, that'll help you set up your system so that you can install Windows on it. [This one](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=YFF1M) here is compatible with a 2850 and Windows 2008 R2.

Someone on [the Dell forums](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/1466/p/19465175/20178388#20178388) was able to get 2012 up and running on a 2800, which someone in [the Spiceworks community](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/293356-unable-to-install-server-2012-on-dell-poweredge-2850-perc-4e-di) was able to replicate with a 2850 and 2012 R2. These methods are not supported by Dell, so your mileage may vary.